# return statement in a function as class

Tags: javascript

I am confused about the return statement in a function that serves as a class. See the example code below:

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
    this.abc = 'def';
    return 3;
}

var mytest = new test(); 

document.write(mytest + ', ' + (typeof mytest) + ', ' + mytest.abc);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The code out put: [object Object], object, def.

Here is my question. I wrote 'return 3' in the test() function. Is this statement ignored when 'new test()' is called?

Thanks.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have classes. Objects in js are based on prototypes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call a function with `new`, you're invoking it as a constructor which automatically returns the new object it constructs.

Your `return 3;` statement is ignored. What is returned is effectively:

```
{ abc:'def' }
```

...with an implicit reference to a `prototype` object, which in your example doesn't have any enumerable properties because you haven't given it any.

If you did:

```
mytest instanceof test;
```

...it would evaluate to `true`.

If you did:

```
function test() {
    this.abc = 'def';
}
test.prototype.ghi = 'jkl';

var mytest = new test();
```

...you could then do:

```
mytest.ghi;
```

...which would give you the value `'jkl'`.

Comment: It is only ignored if the return value is not an object. Otherwise it has a [different behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770070/return-statement-in-a-function-as-class#42603663)

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `new` operator, you're using the function as a constructor, in that case for the return value:

- if it's **not an object**, it is ignored (like in your example)
- if it **is an object**, the object returned becomes the result of the whole `new` expression

So if you were to write

```
Test = function(arg) {
    this.a = 1;
    return arg;
}

var t1 = new Test(10);
var t2 = new Test({b: 2}); 
console.log(t1, t2)
// output:
//   Test {a:1}   Object {b: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new` operator instantiates and returns an *object*. Here are some examples with its output:

```
(...)
var mytest = test();
document.write(mytest + ', ' + (typeof mytest) + ', ' + mytest.abc); 
// 3, number, undefined
```

Or:

```
function test() {
    this.abc = 'def';
    this.getvalue = function(){
        return 3;
    }
}
var mytest = new test(); 
document.write(mytest.getvalue() + ', ' + (typeof mytest) + ', ' + mytest.abc);
// 3, object, def
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```js
function test(){
this.abc = "def"
this.ghi = function(){
return "jkl"
}
}
```

or

```js
function test(){
this.Class = function(){
this.def = "abc"
this.jkl = "ghi"
}
this.abc = "def"
this.ghi = function(){
return "jkl"
}
}
```